# Filling out multiple forms stored in the session var

Tags: php, session

I'm just curious about best practice here...

I have a multipage form that a user fills out.. at the moment, I store the form data in a session var.

If a user opens a new tab to fill in the same form with slightly different details, the 2 tabs conflict each other.

My thoughts were to generate maybe a uniqueid upon a new request to fill out the form, then keep this held in a `?id=uniqueid` var in the URL so I could track which form their filling out.

Then in the PHP, add / edit / modify the session data according to `$_SESSION[uniqueid]['formdata']`...

Just wondering if anyone else had any other solution to this?

Comment: Or maybe save the data in a session array

`$_SESSION[formdata][] = $data;`

and then just loop through it or whatever u want

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps assign an ID based on the form stage to prevent the user inadvertently tampering with the URL.

```
$_SESSION['form1'] = $_POST;
```

If the user opens a new tab, or returns to the form later, you can then take them to the correct stage of the form based on which session keys are set. Or, if you use a multi-dimensional array:

```
$_SESSION['form']['form1'] = ...;
...
$_SESSION['form']['form2'] = ...;
```

You can count the session form array to get the latest stage they filled in.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['form']))
{
    $currentFormId = 'form' . count($_SESSION['form']);
}
```

Depending on what the form is for, you might want to unset the session form key when the final stage has been submitted.